# Storing socket.io data

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm developing an app using socket.io where users send and receive data to users who are present in there channels/rooms. Here, I need your suggestion for storing data that is passed from user to a channel. So when some one enters that channel he should be able to get the data from that particular channel he entered.

So how will I save the data to the particular channel?

I had planned for storing data in MySQL database, which will have channel id, channel name, and channel message columns.

But I think it will be a problem if number of users increases and inserting each message as a new row into database?

Please help me the best way for these query.

Comment: Why would it be a problem to have many users inserting new messages as new rows?  That's exactly how you should be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Until you have thousands of simultaneous users, it hardly matters.  Just use whatever you are most comfortable with. When you get thousands of users you can change the architecture, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for replying, i gonna try MySQL database idea itself.